# How can I use sibling CSS selectors?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, siblings

```
  $('#0show').hide();
  $('#0click').click(function(event) {
     $('#0show').toggle();
     $('#1show').hide();
     $('#2show').hide();
  });    

  $('#1show').hide();
  $('#1click').click(function(event) {
     $('#1show').toggle();
     $('#0show').hide();
     $('#2show').hide();
  });        

  $('#2show').hide();
  $('#2click').click(function(event) {
     $('#2show').toggle();
     $('#0show').hide();
     $('#1show').hide();
  });
```

I'm trying to make my code more resuable, and I'd like to use sibling selectors. Essentially I have to change my dom because all shows are the same, so I would make just a show class? but how do I use these selectors in css?

html (which I need to edit, to use as some suggest classes)

```
<a class='clicked' href='#' id='0click'>Reveal Image Uploader</a> 
<div id='0show'> 
    <div class='column first'> 
        <div class='fieldWithUpload' id='upload_id_5' style='margin-top: 10px'> 
            <div class='uploadHolder'> 
                <div id='bgUploaderButton'></div> 
                    <span class='uploadProgressbar'></span> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI...you should not begin your element ID's with a number.  This may work in some browsers but I think it will cause trouble for you later on down the road.  At least, it is a W3C recommendation: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html

Comment: Can you provide us your html, thx

Comment: @Knix  rumor has it that you can in HTML5 http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: @3nigma interesting. Thanks for the heads up. I love the example given `<p class="++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.">Hello world!` LOL

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple pattern for multiple open/close sections. You don't need to use IDs

```
<a class='link' href='javascript://'>Reveal Image Uploader</a> 
<div style="display:none" class="details"> ... </div>
```

JS:

```
$('.link').click(function) {
    $('.details').hide()
    $(this).next('.details').show()
}
```